# Meaning of notation $\mathbb{Q}^\wedge k$, $-\infty^\wedge \mathbb{Q}$ for linear orders

Tags: lo.logic, notation

I am reading Friedman & Stanley *A Borel reducibility theory for classes of countable structures* (J. Symbolic Logic 54 (1989), 894–914; [MR1011177](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1011177)) and a caret (${}^\wedge$) appears as notation in the following contexts without definition:

1. $\mathbb{Q} \times (-\infty^\wedge \mathbb{Q})$.  The type of $(-\infty^\wedge \mathbb{Q})$ should be a linear order.
2. $\sigma^\wedge m$, where $\sigma \in \omega^n$ and $m \in \omega$.  The type of the result should be an element of $\omega^{n+1}$.
3. $ \mathbb{Q}^\wedge k + 2^\wedge \mathbb{Q}$ where $k$ is an integer.  The type of the result should be a linear order.

Context on (1) suggests that $-\infty^\wedge \mathbb{Q}$ should be the linear order obtained by adding a bottom element to $\mathbb{Q}$.  The intended meaning of (2) is clear.  I would like to know what (3) means!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like a primitive concatenation symbol, like what might today be denoted $\sigma^\frown\eta$, and this would align with your expectation in the last paragraph. If we regard $k$ as the $k$ point order (as it is with the von Neumann ordinals), then  $\mathbb{Q}$^$k$ would mean adding k points on top of the rational order, and $2$^$\mathbb{Q}$ would mean adding two points at the bottom of the rational order.

Comment: This is the same meaning as $+$ when applied to orders, which suggests to me that their $+$ is something else. In particular, the whole expression should be probably parsed as $\mathbb Q^\wedge(k+2)^\wedge\mathbb Q$ rather than $(\mathbb Q^\wedge k)+(2^\wedge\mathbb Q)$.

Comment: Then what is addition?  It seems plausible that it would be a coproduct, but that would be a partial order (made of two incomparable linear orders).  Alternatively, if it was concatenation then that would use the caret.  And if it was the set of sums of each pair, then it would be difficult to understand what that could mean.

Comment: Oh, Emil's comment (which I didn't see when I wrote mine) makes a lot more sense.  It is funny how I make implicit assumptions about order of operations.

Comment: I agree with Emil.

Comment: Jason, I had the same assumption you did, which fueled my confusion!  Thanks, everyone.